# docker doesn't store data to expected directory when using volume param

Tags: docker

I'm running Docker Desktop (4.24.2) on Windows 10 (with WSL 2).

I run the following command to run a container:
`docker run -p 3306:3306 -v /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true --name=mysql1 mysql`

I use a mysql admin application (HeidiSQL) to add a database and table with some records. This works fine. However, when I inspect the folders in the docker-desktop-data folder, there is no `opt/data` folder to be found. So it looks like the -v param is not working?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer here: [Mounting a host directory as a data volume doesn’t work as expected](https://forums.docker.com/t/mounting-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume-doesnt-work-as-expected/8111)

It says: "Only the `C:\Users` area of the host file system is shared with the container and thus mountable."

Using below command is now working:
`docker run -p 3306:3306 -v /c/Users/User/Volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true --name=mysql1 mysql`

Since the docker examples I was learning from were using linux, it was unclear to me whether the "host" file system on Windows should be in the WSL, or the Windows file system itself. The above link clarified that it is actually the Windows file system.

With the current version of docker, the folder no longer needs to be under `C:\Users`. It can be under `C:\`.